# Spring - @Autowired method when execute

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

I have a `BaseDaoImpl` class, it has following method:

```
@Autowired
public void initSessionFactory(@Qualifier("sqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
    super.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
    System.out.println("------ ok ------");
}
```

I defined a subclass `UserDaoImpl`, which `implements BaseDaoImpl`. And defined it as a bean.
When init Spring context, I found that the `initSessionFactory()` method is executed automatically, but I didn't call any methods.
In my understanding, the method is executed & autowire its params only when I call it, can someone help to explain how it works? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That behavior is normal. Your `initSessionFactory` method annotated with `@Autowired` is considered to be a *config method*. `@Autowired` can be placed on constructors, fields and methods. When the bean is created, first the constructor is called, then the fields are injected and then config methods are called.

A config method's (annotated with `@Autowired`) arguments will be autowired with a matching bean in the Spring container.

See the [Javadoc API for Autowired annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want to know.